# Почему в этом коде используется throw?

Tags: java, android, исключения

```
private static String getOperandText(EditText operandEditText)  {
    String operandText = operandEditText.getText().toString();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(operandText)){
        throw new NumberFormatException("Operand cannot be empty");
    }
    return operandText;
}

private static Double getOperand(EditText operandEditText) {
    String operandText = getOperandText(operandEditText);
    return Double.valueOf(operandText);
}
```

В этом коде я получаю число, которое ввел в EditText, и если оно пустое то выбрасывается исключение. Так вот почему именно нужно выбросить исключение. Почему нельзя сделать

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(operandText)){
    TextView.setText("Cannot be empty")
}
```

Вот код который вызывает этот метод:

```
private void compute(Calculator.Operator operator) {
    double operandOne;
    double operandTwo;
    try {
        operandOne = getOperand(mOperandOneEditText);
        operandTwo = getOperand(mOperandTwoEditText);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NumberFormatException", nfe);
        mResultTextView.setText(getString(R.string.computationError));
        return;
    }

    String result;
    switch (operator) {
        case ADD:
            result = String.valueOf(
                    mCalculator.add(operandOne, operandTwo));
            break;
        case SUB:
            result = String.valueOf(
                    mCalculator.sub(operandOne, operandTwo));
            break;
        case DIV:
            result = String.valueOf(
                    mCalculator.div(operandOne, operandTwo));
            break;
        case MUL:
            result = String.valueOf(
                    mCalculator.mul(operandOne, operandTwo));
            break;
        default:
            result = getString(R.string.computationError);
            break;
    }
    mResultTextView.setText(result);
}
```

И я не пойму, что делает **return** внутри блока **catch**?
Он завершает метод compute ??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это концептуально спорный вопрос.

Некоторые считают, что если на вход в метод приходят не валидные параметры или какие-то данные, необходимые для вычисления, не валидны, то нужно выбрасывать исключение. Вполне распространённая практика.

Вот только в вашем примере, оно реализовано наполовину. Методы, выбрасывающие исключение, должны указывать, какие исключения могут быть выброшены:

```
private static String getOperandText(EditText operandEditText) throws NumberFormatException {
    String operandText = operandEditText.getText().toString();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(operandText)){
        throw new NumberFormatException("Operand cannot be empty");
    }
    return operandText;
}
```

Ну а `return` в `catch` выходит из метода. Т.е, метод `compute` дальше выполняться не будет.

В вашем примере даже если `getOperandText` не выбросить исключение, а просто вернёт `null`, то `NumberFormatException` всё равно вылетит в `getOperand` на строке [`Double.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Как я понял, если не выбросить исключение в этом коде, то catch не сработает и метод compute будет дальше выполняться с пустым значением ? Или будет ошибка NullPointer?

Comment: @Rarity7- в вашем примере `getOperandText` вообще не вызывается. Там в `try` вызов `getOperand`.

Comment: Ой, сори я забыл добавить еще один метод. Исправил. Теперь вызывается:)

Comment: @Rarity7- обновил ответ.

Comment: !!Все,Понял..!!